Return 403 forbidden in production env
I have issue when try to perform the api in production environment, but it works it my staging environment. This is my code for the api
import prisma from '../../../prisma/db';
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const {
    introduction, projectId,
  } = req.body;

  // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
  switch (req.method) {
    case 'PUT':
      try {
        const updateIntroduction = await prisma.project.update({
          where: {
            project_id: parseInt(projectId, 10),
          },
          data: {
            introduction,
          },
        });
        res.json('ok');
        console.log('PUT /api/introduction: ', updateIntroduction);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('PUT /api/introduction: ', error);
        res.json(error);
      }
      break;
  }
}


const requestOption = {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
};

try {
  const response = await fetch('/api/introduction', requestOption);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to update introduction');
  }
  const responseData = await response.json();
  setIntroShow(false);
  return responseData;
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error updating introduction:', error);
  setIntroShow(false); 
  throw error;
  // Or handle the error gracefully here, e.g., show an error message to the user
}


};

It throws:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "
<h"... is not valid JSON.

Example of data:
The value is via 5000L and 2500L translucent tanks.
But then i notice when i remove "and" word,  data is successfully add to database. Also i notice some character (ABC) (DFE) also return error, but if i make it ABC (DFE) it successfull.
make sure all type of text can go through the api.
